# How can I make separate pull-requests for each commit in GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request

I made two changes on a project in GitHub (two commits). How can I create two different pull requests from my changes?

I only found a way to create one big pull request that includes all my changes: https://github.com/tcatm/ffmap-d3/pull/22

Comment: I know that in the desktop GUI for GitHub, you can select which files to commit. This way you could select some files, make a pull request, then select the rest, and make another pull request. I have done this on the Mac OSX version of GitHub (I cannot be sure if it is do-able on the Windows version)

Comment: I thought of that, but I already committed both changes. I missed to create a pull request before committing the second changes. Do I have to revert the second commit, create the first pull request and then re-commit hte second changes?

Comment: Yes, I think that may be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this with the [SmartGit/hg](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) GUI:

- open the log of the master branch
- right-click on the first revision from the time, you forked the main project and create a new branch from there
- switch into that branch in the left bottom corner with right-click
- cherry-pick the revisions you want to make a separate pull request and commit them as one commit
- push your new branch up on GitHub
- there you can create a pull request from just that branch

for the second pull request, you create a new branch and do the same with it

Answer (score 1):

Create a new **branch**:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b mybranch
... make changes ...
git add myfile
git commit
git push -u origin mybranch
```

Then create a pull request and change the last **compare** button on [github](https://github.com) to `mybranch`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some screenshots taken from the Mac OSX version of the GitHub desktop program.

Here I am making the first commit, but you can see both changes have been made prior to the commit:
[image: Commit #1]

Here I am making the second commit:
[image: Commit #2]

Here you can see that each commit was accepted individually:
[image: Overview]

- Note: Some names have been blanked out for privacy.

Assuming that the Windows version of GitHub has the same options, I would download the desktop program and try that.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? Or am I confused?

Comment: no, I clarified it in a comment to the main question. By the way: (not really unfortunately) I use only Linux, and there seems no gitHub GUI yet